# R insert week number from vector and perform na.locf afterwards

Tags: r, locf

For a dataframe similar to below (but much larger obviously)) I want to add missing week numbers from a vector ( vector is named weeks below). In the end, each value for var1 should have 4 rows consisting of week 40 - 42 so the value inserted for week can be different for different values of var1. Initially the inserted rows can have value `NA` but as a second step I would like to perform `na.locf` for each value of var1. does anyone know how to do this?

Data frame example:

```
dat <- data.frame(var1 = rep(c('a','b','c','d'),3),
                  week = c(rep(40,4),rep(41,4),rep(42,4)),
                  value = c(2,3,3,2,4,5,5,6,8,9,10,10))
dat <- dat[-c(6,11), ]

weeks <- c(40:42)
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: `dat2 <- merge(data.frame(var1=rep(letters[1:4], length(weeks)), week=rep(weeks, e=4)), dat, by=c("var1", "week"), all=TRUE); dat2 <- dat2[order(dat2$var1, dat2$week), ]; dat2$value <- zoo::na.locf(dat2$value)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
dat %>% 
   tidyr::complete(var1,week) %>% 
   group_by(var1) %>% 
   arrange(week) %>% 
   tidyr::fill(value)
# A tibble: 12 x 3
# Groups:   var1 [4]
   var1   week value
   <fct> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 a        40     2
 2 a        41     4
 3 a        42     8
 4 b        40     3
 5 b        41     3
 6 b        42     9
 7 c        40     3
 8 c        41     5
 9 c        42     5
10 d        40     2
11 d        41     6
12 d        42    10
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi have you considered tidyr::complete and dplyr::fill().

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

complete(dat, week = 40:42, var1 = c("a", "b", "c", "d")) %>% fill(value, .direction = 
"down")
```